# Odd first run behavior, possible Swift timing issue?

Tags: swiftui

I'm finishing up online auditing of Stanford CS193P class (great class BTW) and I have an oddity on my last assignment. I have created a theme data store and I use it to select a theme (color, number of pairs of cards, emoji) and then kick off and play a matching game. That works fine. Using an edit button, the user can edit a theme and change any of the theme elements.

I run into a problem the first time I use the edit button and select a theme to edit. My code acts as if the @State myEditTheme is nil. If I force unwrap it it crashes. I have put it in a nil-coalescing option as shown, the edit window comes up with the first theme in the array. Any subsequent edit attempts work normally.

In the tap gesture function, I set the value of the @State var myEditTheme, then I set the themeEditing to true. My debug print statement indicates that the myEditTheme has been properly set. When the sheet(isPresented: $themeEditing) presents the ThemeEditor in a "sheet" view, the initial value of myEditTheme is nil.

Is there a timing issue between when I set it in the tap function and when Swift senses that themeEditing is true? The code below is obviously not functional as is, I have edited it for conciseness, only showing relevant portions.

```
struct ThemeManager: View {
@EnvironmentObject var store: ThemeStore // injected
    

@State private var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
// inject a binding to List and Edit button

@State private var myEditTheme: Theme?

@State private var themeEditing = false
// used to control .sheet presentation for theme editing

    
var body: some View {
        
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(store.themes) { theme in
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(viewModel: EmojiMemoryGame(theme: theme))) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(theme.name).font(.title2)
                        Text(theme.emojis).lineLimit(1)        
                    } // end VStack
                    
                    .sheet(isPresented: $themeEditing) {
                        ThemeEditor(theme: $store.themes[myEditTheme ?? theme])
                            .environmentObject(store)
                    }
                    
                    .gesture(editMode == .active ? tap(theme) : nil)
                                            
                } // end NavigationLink
            } // end ForEach
        } // end List
        

        .navigationTitle("Themes")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) // removes large title, leaves small inline one
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem { EditButton() }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                newThemeButton
            }
        }
        .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
        
    } // NavigationView
    
} // body


private func tap(_ theme:Theme) -> some Gesture {
    TapGesture().onEnded {
        myEditTheme = theme
        print("edit theme: \(myEditTheme)")
        themeEditing = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Without a [mre] it's hard to debug this exactly, but this looks like a situation where you should be using `sheet(item:)` and passing in a specific theme rather than `sheet(isPresented:)`

Comment: That wouldn't work for me as the sheet should only be presented when we're in edit mode to edit a theme. The themeEditing var can only be set to true in the tap gesture function and the tap gesture is only accessible in edit mode.

Comment: I don’t see why any of that as antithetical to what I suggested -- the item can be an optional.

Comment: use the `.sheet(item)` instead

Comment: I switched over to use .sheet(item:) as suggested and I get identically the same behavior (myEditTheme is nil first time through) which is possibly more odd as the developer doc says "When item is non-nil, the system passes the item’s content to the modifier’s closure".

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm calling it as   .sheet(item: $myEditTheme) {_ in
                            ThemeEditor(theme: $store.themes[myEditTheme ?? theme])
                                .environmentObject(store)
                        }